# How can i build android app on my server?

Tags: android

Good Morning,

I have an android application and I sell it on a third-party website so, my customers need to configure it. My question is, can they build my app online without the need to open android studio also, they will only change one line like (SECRET_API_KEY) and that. Can I upload my app source code on my website and build it online? I see that websites like appyet.com use the online build for apps! As I said, I just need to change one line and change package-name online that's my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can. You don't actually need Android Studio to build your app: under the hood, Android Studio uses gradle scripts to build it. All you need is a server with Java and the Android SDK installed, so you can build the app from command line.

The solution is a CI/CD solution like Gitlab or Jenkins. Both can be installed on your own server, or you can subscribe to their website and pay a small fee. When the app is bought, the build can be triggered with a webhook by your server.

A few questions come to mind:

- How many app do you think you think you'll sell? In other words, is it worth the time to set this up?
- What do you want as the end result? A link to an .APK on your website, a link to the Play Store?
- If you update the app, do you want previous buyers to receive an update?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer and sorry for the late response :)

1. I developed the app to fully work with remote config so, you can manage design, configuration and track the app from console made for you after purchase app. In other words, you just need to write one line to use the whole app and change package name then all configuration will be online and updates too. So, i think it worth when complete the idea of remote config and i think this will make a good opportunity for customers who don't know anything about android studio or android.

Comment: 2. Yes i need a link to the generated app on so, my customers can download their apk and they can manage it from their console and i connect with the app using an api and a secret key for every customer.

3. I already manage that when update my app. I send them emails, notifications and some customers enables an option to update their app without need to approve it.

I have looked at Jenkins, i think it's very good to use but i didn't got it very much about Gitlab. If you have any links or references for the best way i can use it. I learned how to setup it on server Thank you again :)

Comment: @AbdelrahmanAshref sounds interesting, do you have any update on that?